# Passing class object between forms but object is null C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pass two player class objects between CharacterCreationMenu form and MainGame forms.

When user enters into form all the date and clicks button this code gets executed:

```
        string playerUsername,
        playerClass;

        Player player1 = new();
        Player player2 = new();

        if (cbClass0.Text == "Warrior")
        {
            playerUsername = txtBoxUsername0.Text;
            playerClass = cbClass0.Text;
            List<string> playerAbilities = new() { "Heroic Strike", "Overpower", "Revenge" };

            player1 = new(playerUsername, playerClass, playerAbilities);
        }

        else if (cbClass0.Text == "Mage")
        {
            playerUsername = txtBoxUsername0.Text;
            playerClass = cbClass0.Text;
            List<string> playerAbilities = new() { "Fireball", "Frostbolt", "Fire Blast" };

            player1 = new(playerUsername, playerClass, playerAbilities);
        }

        if (cbClass1.Text == "Warrior")
        {
            playerUsername = txtBoxUsername0.Text;
            playerClass = cbClass1.Text;
            List<string> playerAbilities = new() { "Heroic Strike", "Overpower", "Revenge" };

            player2 = new(playerUsername, playerClass, playerAbilities);
        }

        else if (cbClass1.Text == "Mage")
        {
            playerUsername = txtBoxUsername0.Text;
            playerClass = cbClass1.Text;
            List<string> playerAbilities = new() { "Fireball", "Frostbolt", "Fire Blast" };

            player2 = new(playerUsername, playerClass, playerAbilities);
        }

        MainGame mainGame = new();
        mainGame.Player1 = player1;
        mainGame.Player2 = player2;
        mainGame.Show();
        this.Hide();
```

And in my MainGame form I created constructor to pass these objects

```
    public Player Player1 {get;set;}
    public Player Player2 {get;set;}
```

And I'm getting error:

[image: ErrorScreenShot]

Comment: Your `cbClass0.Text` is not equal to the expected string, so you did not initialize Player.Username field and Player.GetUsername() returns null. Also you have initialized your player instances many times. It is not good practice. Have Player class constructor, that takes required info and initializes the class instance accordingly.

Comment: Is it made on purpose to use `txtBoxUsername0.Text` when setting `Player2`'s username ? Can you show us `Player` code ?

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors.

Comment: Does this happen for all characters or only a few? You're using if/elseif and not doing any alternative catching, like the default case for a switch statement. If it's not a warrior or mage then your player doesn't get initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe cbClass0 is never clicked on, try to create instance variable Player **player1** and when combo box is clicked *("you need to subsribe to event onClick on that comboBox")* to the initialization of **player1** instance variable

Comment: So apperiantely there is other problem going on... My code first tries to run before switching to new form (I think?). Cause when I print out the variables in other form the objects are not null. https://imgur.com/a/OHYk0r5

Comment: Is yout Player1's username null or nor null?